# Error running unit tests on PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

I am getting this error when I try to run unit tests with pycharm on my project:

```
/Users/jpfarias/env/bin/python /Applications/Dev/PyCharm 1.5.4.app/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py /Users/jpfarias/src/myproject/ true
Testing started at 6:53 PM ...
invalid command name '/Users/jpfarias/src/myproject/'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any idea what's wrong and how to fix?

I'm using PyCharm 1.5.4 and Python 2.7.1 on a virtual env.